# Qt menu bar events

Tags: c++, qt

I've added menus and menu items in Qt creator using the "Design" option.  I then rt-clicked the associated action below and clicked on "Go to slot".  This takes me to the code that will be executed when I click on that menu item.  Perfect - almost. I'd like to distinguish between clicking and shift-clicking on the menu item. It looks like I can determine whether the event was modified with the shift button by doing something like this:

```
if (event->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier) {
    ...
}
```

The problem is that no event is passed in for a menu click action.

Can I do what I'm trying to do somehow? Do I need to figure out how to pass an event in - or is there some other way to test that the shift key is pressed?

Thanks!

Comment: @LukášBednařík the Qt menu bar system uses `QAction::triggered` for the slots which doesn't pass an event to connected slots, so this information isn't directly available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the slot which is being called you can use [`QGuiApplication::keyboardModifiers()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#keyboardModifiers) to get the current keyboard modifiers:

```
void MainWindow::on_action_triggered() {
    if (QApplication::keyboardModifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier) {
        // Shift key is down.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  You made that way too easy.

Comment: No problem. In that case could you please accept the answer?

Comment: Sorry about that.  That's the first time I've posted a question here.  I didn't know about accepting answers.